# Lag on material ui React input

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a parent component where I call 4 child components with multiple input fields.

When I write on a TextField it looks very slow.
It should be noted that I have already updated all my dependencies, but the problem persists.

This is the code of my parent component.

```
import { Button } from '@mui/material';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Navbar } from '../../Navbar';
import { InfoAcompananteResponsable, InfoContactoPaciente, InfoPacienteEps, InformacionBasica } from './ComponentePaciente';
import styles from "./formPacientes.module.scss";

const FormPacientes = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <>   <Navbar />    </>

            <div className={styles.box_main}>
                <div className={styles.box_title}>
                    <Typography className={styles.h6} variant="h4" color="initial">
                        Registro de Pacientes
                    </Typography>
                </div>
                <form className={styles.form}>
                    <InformacionBasica />
                    <InfoContactoPaciente />
                    <InfoPacienteEps />
                    <InfoAcompananteResponsable />
                    <div className={styles.box_button}>
                        <Button variant="contained">Registrar Paciente</Button>
                        <Button variant="contained">Ir Al listado de Pacientes</Button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </>
    )


}
```

export default FormPacientes`

**This is the code for one of my child components.
**

```
import { AccountCircle } from "@mui/icons-material";
import BadgeIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Badge';
import EventIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Event';
import Grid3x3Icon from '@mui/icons-material/Grid3x3';
import PeopleAltIcon from '@mui/icons-material/PeopleAlt';
import WcIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Wc';
import WorkIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Work';
import { Box, FormControl, FormControlLabel, FormLabel, NativeSelect, Radio, RadioGroup, TextField } from "@mui/material";
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import styles from "./styles/infoBasica.module.scss";

const InformacionBasica = ({ onChange }) => {

    return (
        <Box className={styles.box_main}>
            <Box className={styles.box_column}>

                <Box className={styles.box_textField}>
                    <AccountCircle className={styles.AccountCircle} />
                    <TextField label="Primer Nombre" variant="standard" name="primerNombre"  sx={{ width: "100%" }} />
                </Box>

                <Box className={styles.box_textField}>
                    <AccountCircle sx={{ color: 'action.active', mr: 1, my: 0.5 }} />
                    <TextField label="Segundo nombre" variant="standard" sx={{ width: "100%" }} />
                </Box>

                <Box className={styles.box_textField}>
                    <AccountCircle sx={{ color: 'action.active', mr: 1, my: 0.5 }} />
                    <TextField label="Primer Apellido" variant="standard" sx={{ width: "100%" }} />
                </Box>

                <Box className={styles.box_textField}>
                    <AccountCircle sx={{ color: 'action.active', mr: 1, my: 0.5 }} />
                    <TextField label="Segundo apellido" variant="standard" sx={{ width: "100%" }} />
                </Box>

                <Box className={styles.box_textField}>
                    <Grid3x3Icon sx={{ color: 'action.active', mr: 1, my: 0.5 }} />
                    <TextField label="Edad" variant="standard" sx={{ width: "100%" }} />
                </Box>

                <Box className={styles.box_dateField}>
                    <Box sx={{ width: "6%", height: "40px", display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                        <EventIcon sx={{ color: 'action.active', mr: 1 }} />
                    </Box>
                    <Box sx={{ width: "31%", height: "40px", display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                        <FormLabel >Fecha de Nacimiento</FormLabel>
                    </Box>
                    <Box sx={{ width: "63%", height: "40px", display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center', }} >
                        <TextField type='date' variant="standard" sx={{ width: "100%" }} />
                    </Box>
                </Box>

                <Box sx={{ width: "100%", display: 'flex', alignItems: 'flex-end', marginBottom: 2, marginTop: 2 }}>
                    <PeopleAltIcon sx={{ color: 'action.active', mr: 1, my: 0.5 }} />
                    <NativeSelect
                        sx={{ width: "100%" }}
                        inputProps={{
                            name: 'estado-civil',

                        }}
                    >
                        <option value="">Estado Civíl</option>
                        <option value={1}>Cédula de ciudadanía</option>
                        <option value={2}>Tarjeta de Identidad</option>
                        <option value={3}>Pasaporte</option>
                    </NativeSelect>
                </Box>
            </Box>
            <Box className={styles.box_column}>

                <Box sx={{ width: "100%", display: 'flex', alignItems: 'flex-end', marginBottom: 2, marginTop: 2 }}>
                    <BadgeIcon sx={{ color: 'action.active', mr: 1, my: 0.5 }} />
                    <NativeSelect
                        sx={{ width: "100%" }}
                        inputProps={{
                            name: 'tipo-documento',

                        }}
                    >
                        <option value="">Tipo de documento</option>
                        <option value={1}>Cédula de ciudadanía</option>
                        <option value={2}>Tarjeta de Identidad</option>
                        <option value={3}>Pasaporte</option>
                    </NativeSelect>
                </Box>

                <Box sx={{ width: "100%", display: 'flex', alignItems: 'flex-end', marginBottom: 3 }}>
                    <Grid3x3Icon sx={{ color: 'action.active', mr: 1, my: 0.5 }} />
                    <TextField label="Número de Identificación" variant="standard" sx={{ width: "100%" }} />
                </Box>

                <Box sx={{ width: "100%", display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center', marginBottom: 3 }}>
                    <Box sx={{ width: "6%", height: "40px", display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                        <EventIcon sx={{ color: 'action.active', mr: 1 }} />
                    </Box>
                    <Box sx={{ width: "27%", height: "40px", display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                        <FormLabel >Fecha de Ingreso</FormLabel>
                    </Box>
                    <Box sx={{ width: "70%", height: "40px", display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center', }} >
                        <TextField type='date' variant="standard" sx={{ width: "100%" }} />
                    </Box>
                </Box>

                <Box sx={{ width: "100%", display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center', flexDirection: "row", marginBottom: 2, }}>
                    <FormControl sx={{ width: "100%", display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center', flexDirection: "row", }}   >
                        <WcIcon sx={{ color: 'action.active', mr: 1, my: 0.5, }} />
                        <FormLabel sx={{ mr: 5, }}  >Sexo</FormLabel>
                        <RadioGroup
                            row
                            aria-labelledby="sexo"
                            name="sexo"

                        >
                            <FormControlLabel value="female" control={<Radio />} label="Femenino" />
                            <FormControlLabel value="male" control={<Radio />} label="Masculino" />
                        </RadioGroup>
                    </FormControl>
                </Box>

                <Box sx={{ width: "100%", display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center', flexDirection: "row", marginBottom: 2, }}>
                    <FormControl sx={{ width: "100%", display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center', flexDirection: "row" }}   >
                        <EventIcon sx={{ color: 'action.active', mr: 1, my: 0.5, }} />
                        <FormLabel sx={{ mr: 5, }} >Unidad de medida</FormLabel>
                        <RadioGroup
                            row
                            aria-labelledby="unidad-medida"
                            name="unidad-medida"

                        >
                            <FormControlLabel value="female" control={<Radio />} label="Años" />
                            <FormControlLabel value="male" control={<Radio />} label="Meses" />
                            <FormControlLabel value="male" control={<Radio />} label="Días" />
                        </RadioGroup>
                    </FormControl>
                </Box>

                <Box sx={{ width: "100%", display: 'flex', alignItems: 'flex-end', marginBottom: 3 }}>
                    <Grid3x3Icon sx={{ color: 'action.active', mr: 1, my: 0.5 }} />
                    <TextField label="Hijos" type='number' variant="standard" sx={{ width: "100%" }} />
                </Box>

                <Box sx={{ width: "100%", display: 'flex', alignItems: 'flex-end', marginBottom: 2, marginTop: 2 }}>
                    <WorkIcon sx={{ color: 'action.active', mr: 1, my: 0.5 }} />
                    <NativeSelect
                        sx={{ width: "100%" }}
                        inputProps={{
                            name: 'age',

                        }}
                    >
                        <option value="">Ocupación</option>
                        <option value={1}>Cédula de ciudadanía</option>
                        <option value={2}>Tarjeta de Identidad</option>
                        <option value={3}>Pasaporte</option>
                    </NativeSelect>
                </Box>
            </Box>
        </Box >
    )
};

export default InformacionBasica
```

I have left each of the child components alone and it works well alone, as I add the others it slows down.

I updated all the dependencies and deleted the node_modules folder and ran npm install again, but the problem continues